# Mootools: How to get Behavior worked with ajax-loaded elements?

Tags: ajax, mootools, behavior

I'm using Mootools Behavior - https://github.com/anutron/behavior. It works fine but behavior of elements that are ajax-loaded doesn't apply.

Here's my code:

```
var request = new Request.HTML({
    url: get_url(),
    append: $(api.get('append')),
    evalScripts: true,
    onSuccess: function(){
        window.behavior.apply(document.body);
    }
});
```

And it doesn't work.

(window.behavior is the main Behavior instance)

Thank in advance.

**UPD.** That was my own problem with static loading. The code above should work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to set the second, optional parameter on the Behavior.apply()-method.

Try `window.behavior.apply(document.body, true)` in your success-callback function. Elements which already have been processed will be processed again, if the second parameter "force" is set to true. That could be your problem, if not, check back and let us now please.

Comment: Thanks. Second parameter doesn't help.

Comment: Looks like that only those behavior filters work which already were on the page which updates via ajax. The rest doesn't work and throws error that there's no filter with that name.

Comment: Sorry, that was my problem. The question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of re-applying the behavior to the entire document, re-apply it to the new content only. I use this pattern frequently with success.

```
var target = $(api.get('append')); 
var request = new Request.HTML({
    url: get_url(),
    append: target,
    evalScripts: true,
    onSuccess: function() {window.behavior.apply(target);}
});
```